# React native app works on debug mode, but not works release mode on android

Tags: android, react-native, apk, release

React native app works on debug mode, but not works release mode on android.
It stops when I run the program.
I also tested on a test program without any plugins!

Comment: where did it stopped what is the code if we don't know the problem how we will help you?

Comment: This happens when the release file is executed after installation on the phone.

Comment: `adb logcat *:E` use this in terminal and run your release app in emulator you will track the error

Comment: Do you use drawer navigation? If so make sure to add an import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; statment on index file at top file